# How do you print to console in a Multi-Threaded MEX Function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab, boost, mex

I'm writing a simple producer consumer MEX function which uses the Boost library. I  have manged to get the following program to work without any issues.

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

int producer_count = 0;
boost::atomic_int consumer_count (0);
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<int, boost::lockfree::capacity<1024> > spsc_queue;
const int iterations = 10000000;

void producer()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != iterations; ++i) {
        int value = ++producer_count;
        while (!spsc_queue.push(value));
    }
}

boost::atomic<bool> done (false);

void consumer()
{
    int value;
    while (!done) {
        while (spsc_queue.pop(value))
            ++consumer_count;
    }

    while (spsc_queue.pop(value))
        ++consumer_count;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (!spsc_queue.is_lock_free())
    {
      mexPrintf("boost::lockfree::queue is not lockfree\n");
      mexEvalString("drawnow;");
    }
    else
    {
      mexPrintf("boost::lockfree::queue is lockfree\n");
      mexEvalString("drawnow;");
    }

    boost::thread producer_thread(producer);
    boost::thread consumer_thread(consumer);

    producer_thread.join();
    done = true;
    consumer_thread.join();

    cout << "produced " << producer_count << " objects." << endl;
    cout << "consumed " << consumer_count << " objects." << endl;
}
```

The big problem is I try to include a `mexPrintf()` into the either the producer or consumer method MATLAB just crashes. After doing some investigation I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711801/c-multi-thread-text-output-print-to-dos-console-overlapped-mess-up-the-outputs) which explained this happens because of race conditions. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? I read what the answer said about Mutex, but I do not understand how I would implement such a functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `mexPrintf` from any thread except the main thread. A mutex will not solve your problem.

From the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/mex-api-is-not-thread-safe.html):

> **MEX API Is Not Thread Safe**
>
> Do not call a single session of MATLAB® on separate threads from a MEX file. The MEX and Matrix Library APIs are not multi-threaded.
>
> You can create threads from a C MEX file; however, accessing MATLAB from those threads is not supported. Do not call any MEX API functions from the spawned threads, including `printf`, which is defined as `mexPrintf` in the `mex.h` header file.

If you really need to produce output from these threads, consider implementing a simple messaging system where the threads post a message with the text to be output, and the main thread, instead of waiting with `producer_thread.join();`, sits in a loop looking for messages to print, and prints them with `mexPrintf`.

---

The code below is **not tested**. It's not even been compiled. Consider it pseudo-code. I think this is a reasonable attempt at a solution but there might be much better approaches. Continue at your own risk. :)

```
boost::lockfree::queue<std::string> message_queue;

void producer() {
    //...
    message_queue.push("A string to print!");
    //...
}

void mexFunction( /*...*/ ) {
    // ...
    boost::thread producer_thread(producer);
    boost::thread consumer_thread(consumer);
    while(producer_thread.joinable()) {
        join_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        std::string s;
        while (message_queue.pop(s)) {
            mexPrintf("%s\n", s.c_str());
        }
    }
    producer_thread.join();
    done = true;
    consumer_thread.join();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it's not possible. Could you expand on you explanation of how I could implement a messaging system? Some example code would really be appreciated.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker: Sorry, I have little experience with that, I'm afraid I'd recommend something that's wrong. I imagine you'd do, in main, a `while(joinable())` loop, with a `join_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(50))` wait inside. Then you'd have a linked list of messages, which you'd print and remove from the list within this loop. The worker threads would append to the list. The list would be protected by a `std::mutex` for multi-threaded access (or use `boost::lockfree::queue` instead, which has the mutex built in). But this is my low-experience guess at a solution.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker: I've added a bit of code, for how I thought about this solution. I'm not sure even if it would compile... :)

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the new [C++ mex interface](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cpp-mex-file-applications.html). Here you can call matlab functions using feval or fevalAsync. fevalAsync is the way to go when calling matlab from another thread.

A function to print to the command window would look like this:

```
 void print(const std::string& msg)
 {
    mattlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;
    matlabPtr->fevalAsync(u"fprintf", 0,
        std::vector<matlab::data::Array>({ factory.createScalar(msg) }));
 });
```

The problem however is that the messages are displayed after the mex function has finished. Also subsequent calls like

```
matlabPtr->evalAsync(u"pause(0.001);");
```

have no effect. If anyone has an idea, I would also appreciate it.